# Kivy SQLalchemy and Android, No module named MySQLdb

Tags: android, python, mysql, buildozer

I'm building an app for android and i need to interact with Mysql database. I have some problem at configuring access from android but not with my linux installation.

I have succesfully imported the recipe of SQLAlchemy on my android apk but when i run the app trough logcat i see the error:

```
NO module named MySQLdb
```

so i tried adding in buildozer also the recipe of MySQLdb and it says:

```
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

This is the part of the code invoking mysql part:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

def check_sql_list(_id, string):
    cur = engine.connect()
    res = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user")
    for x in res.fetchall():
        if x[_id] == string: return True
    cur.close()

def create_user(name,e_mail,psw):
    if check_sql_list(1,name):
        print 'Select another username.'
    elif check_sql_list(2,e_mail):
        print 'Your E-Mail have already an account.'
    else:
        connection = engine.raw_connection()
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.callproc("sp_createUser",[name, e_mail, psw])
            results = list(cursor.fetchall())
            for a in cursor.fetchall():
                print a
            print results
            cursor.close
            connection.commit()
        finally:
            connection.close()
            print 'Account registered succesfully.'

ip = 'localhost'
databs = 'mydb'
user = 'guest'
psw = 'password'
porta = '3306'

engine = create_engine('mysql://' + user + ':' + psw + '@' + ip + ':' + porta + '/' + databs)
create_user('user001','mail@001.com','password')
```

How can i connect to my database without the needing of MySQLdb recipe? Or where i can find that recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to my own question hoping someone will find it usefull.

I find out how to solve it, use as a dialer mysql+mysqlconnector like:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user00:psw@localhost:3306/database')
```

and adds the recipe requirements in the buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = kivy,sqlalchemy,mysql_connector
```

Answer (score 0):

> kivy -m pip install mysql-connector

than:

> import mysql.connector

working for me :)